# Finding Black border dimensions with Imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick

I would like to know if there is any way I can find the dimensions (top,bottom,left,right) of black border around the image using Imagemagick.

[image: Sample Image]

I believe the dimensions black border of this image are
top and bottom = 10 pixels ,
left and right = 5 pixels
but how do I go about finding all four those dimensions using imagemagick or any other tool.

Any help or hint for my problem will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always provide your ImageMagick version and which OS you're working on.

If you're using IMv7 you can find the widths of those borders with a command like this...

```
magick input.jpg -fuzz 10% -set page "%[@]" -format "Left: %[fx:page.x] Right: %[fx:w-page.width-page.x] Top: %[fx:page.y] Bottom: %[fx:h-page.height-page.y]\n" info:
```

That does a sort of pseudo-trim with "-set page "%[@]"" and stores the dimensions and offsets in variables you can access using FX expressions. Since the black border on your example isn't all one color because of JPG compression, I had to use "-fuzz 10%" ahead of that setting to adjust the tolerance of the trim.

Learn more about FX expressions [at THIS link](https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php).